# Gate corresponding to $-I$

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, qiskit, circuit-construction

I am implementing a quantum circuit in Qiskit. I create the equal superposition state 
$$
-|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle +|11\rangle  
$$
but I want to obtain the quantum state
$$
|00\rangle - |01\rangle - |10\rangle -|11\rangle . 
$$

In general, when I have $n$ qubits, I want to put a -1 coefficient in front of every state except $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$. This transformation corresponds to $-I$ matrix. Which gate(s) should I apply to my circuit to have this transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your states differ in global phase only, hence they are indistinguishable (or in other words they are equivalent). Therefore you do not need to apply gate $-I$.

*Note that the global phase is $\pi$ as $-1 = \mathrm{e}^{i\pi}$*

---

However, in case the state is produced by controlled gate, global phase cannot be neglected. In that case you can implement controlled $-I$ as $Z \otimes I$, i.e. $Z$ gate is applied on controlling qubit and identity gates on controlled qubits.

Just to show that $Z \otimes I$ is controlled global phase $\pi$ (or in other words controlled gate $-I$):

$$
C(-I) = \begin{pmatrix} I & O \\ O & -I \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}= 
Z \otimes I
$$